# how to keep the head of a linked list in c language?

Tags: c, list, linked-list

i have managed to read data from a file and store them into a linked list, but the problem is that i lost the head, so when ever i try to print the data it print the last one then the one before and so on.

the file is something like this :

tom;14

sara;19

this is the code i use to read the data :

```
   if ( f != NULL ) {
    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), f ) != NULL ) {
        person*n= (person*) malloc( sizeof( process ) );

        name = strtok( buffer, ";\n\r\t" );
        strcpy( n->NAME, name);

        age= strtok( NULL, ";\n\r\t" );
        n->AGE= atoi(age);
        n->next= head;
        head = n;
    }

    fclose( f );
```

the output is like this :

sara; 19

tom;14

when ever i use head in a print function it starts printing from the last element, so my guess is that head didn't point to the first element when i finished reading the data. My solution was to use another pointer , so i used head2 like this :

i put head2 = NULL, and when reading i did this :

```
if(head2==NULL) head2=n;
```

but again, i faced another problem, because when i use head2 in a print function it only print the first element :

tom;14

Any help on this problem please ?

Comment: There seems to be a bracket missing in the cast from the return of `malloc`; is that the case?

Comment: it's not the problem that you've "lost the head pointer". The problem is that you're inserting to the front of the list, so when you're reading it from the front, you access the elements in the reverse order. You may try inserting to the back (`O(n)` for each element naively, or `O(1)` with a bit of trickery by saving the tail pointer after each insertion). Alternatively, you may try writing a recursive traversal function which prints the elements from the back to the front (something along the lines of `if (node == 0) return; recursive_print(node->next); printf(/* whatever */, node->data);`.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant i did make a reverse print function, but i need the head for other functions

Comment: @alex why "but"? said reverse print function doesn't need to alter, burn in fire or magically hide your head pointer…

Comment: This will only work if `head` is a global variable. If `head` is passed as a function argument (you have not posted enough code for us to see), or declared in the function then the new value of `head` will be lost on return from the function.

Comment: @alex, you are not grasping what TPC told you.  The "head" of a linked list conventionally means its first element in traversal order (not the first one added).  You are not losing yours, but you are changing which node is the head by adding each new element at the beginning of the list.  If you want the list order to match the order of items in the file, then you must instead add each new item at the *end* of the list.

Comment: Thank you all, i finally got it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( f != NULL ) {
while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), f ) != NULL ) {
    person*n= (person*) malloc( sizeof( process ) );

    name = strtok( buffer, ";\n\r\t" );
    strcpy( n->NAME, name);

    age= strtok( NULL, ";\n\r\t" );
    n->AGE= atoi(age);
    n->next= NULL;
    //note from here
    if(end!=NULL)
        end->next=n;
    end=n;
    if(head==NULL)  
        head = n;
}

fclose( f );
```

You simply are inserting in the starting of the link list. You need to insert in the beginning.
*Set head only once. You're changing head everytime for every iteration of while loop. Place a null check to set it only once in starting. For inserting in the end of link list take another pointer end that stores the address of last node.*

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct yourstruct * PtrToStruct;

struct yourstruct
{
  char NAME[512];
  int Age;
  PtrToStruct Next;
};

void Insert(PtrToStruct);
void ReadFromFile(PtrToStruct);


int  main ()
{
  struct yourstruct  head;  // using the dummy element 
  head.Next = NULL;

  ReadFromFile(&head);      //sending address of dummy element


 return 0;
}

void ReadFromFile(PtrToStruct P)
{

 FILE *dat;
 char name[512];
 PtrToStruct temp;
 char buffer[512];

 printf("\nEnter the name of file");
 scanf(" %s", name);

 dat = fopen(name, "r");

 if (NULL == dat)
    printf("\n Does not exist");
 else
 {
    while(fgets( buffer, sizeof( buffer ), dat ) != NULL )
    {
        temp = (PtrToStruct)malloc(sizeof(struct yourstruct));

        name = strtok( buffer, ";\n\r\t" );
        strcpy( temp->NAME, name);

        age= strtok( NULL, ";\n\r\t" );
        temp->Age= atoi(age);

        temp->Next = P->Next;
        P->Next= temp;
        P = temp;
    }

    fclose(dat);
  }

}
```